# POST instead of GET parameter

Tags: php, post, get

Is there a way of producing POST instead of GET parameter by clicking on this link:

```
<?
   $dir="images/custom/";// putia do dir-a
   $handle = opendir($dir);
   if ($handle) {
   while (($file=readdir($handle))!==false) {
   echo '<center><a href="?cust='.$file.'"><img src="images/custom/'.$file.'  "title="Click to set it" "></a></center><br />'; } } 
?>
```

Comment: Not as it is, but JavaScript can be used to instantiate or populate an existing form with the necessary value and POST it. Many PHP frameworks also supply a method out of the box to make a "post link" which abstracts away that functionality.

Comment: The simplest way is by submitting a form. I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Just by clicking a link? No. You could perhaps intercept the click in Javascript and rework the request that way.

Comment: just wondering, why do you need POST instead of GET?

Comment: You can't produce a POST request from a href. You can, instead, use Javascript to handle an onclick event to send the desired POST request with the data you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `<a>` to a form submit:

```
<?php

   $dir="images/custom/";// putia do dir-a
   $handle = opendir($dir);
   if ($handle) {
   while (($file=readdir($handle))!==false) {
       echo '<center><form method="post" action="?cust='.$file.'"><input id="test1" name="test1" type="image" src="images/custom/'.$file.'" title="Click to set it" /></form></center><br />';
   }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That did it:

```
 echo'<form action="" method="post">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="parentNode.submit();"><center><img src=images/custom/'.$file.' title="Click to set it" /></center></a>
<input type="hidden" name="mess" value='.$file.' />
</form>';
```

thank you for your answers, 
Regards.